# Is pictureBox the best way to draw a line

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

iam drawing trajectory of a device on real time basis sending data via serial port. Iam using a picturebox and bitmap image(so that trajectory is not gone when my window is not active) to plot the path.

The problem is that the drawing the path is using 20% of CPU (Intel Pentium 4, 3.0 GHz) and i think its too much. Is picture box the correct way to plot the path??

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If your just looking to draw a line then take a look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287522%28v=vs.71%29.aspx